# how to deattach global event in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.2

created a global beforeFind() listener for my find queries but need to detach it for some requests..
$this->eventManager()->off() in controller is not working. i.e. not deattach the event.
In my bootstrap.php file :

```
$modelListerner = new DeletedListener(); //my custom listerner
EventManager::instance()->on(
        $modelListerner
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot locally detach a global listener, you have to detach it globally, ie via

```
EventManager::getInstance()->off(/* ... */);
```

However you may want to consider whether passing options to the finder may be a better solution, so that your controllers do not have to know about listeners and the like, but just execute the find calls as needed, like

```
$Table->find('all', ['doThisAndThat' => false]);
```

and your listener could then act accordingly.

Quote from the docs

> [...] Any options that are not in this list will be passed to beforeFind listeners where they can be used to modify the query object.

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieveing Data & Result Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**